# Using an associated event with an asynchronous file (through OVERLAPPED) will implicitely close the event handle as well when closing the file handle?

Tags: windows, file, events, asynchronous

It is not clear about what to do with the associated event (OVERLAPPED.hEvent) to an asynchronous file being closed: would it be closed as well or would it be considered as a handle leak?

```
    void Close()
    {
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != file)
        {
            // TOCHECK: should the associated events be closed explicitly?
            for (long i = 0; i < overlapped_max; ++i)
            {
                DWORD  dummy;
                auto & overlapped = overlapped_array[i];

                // wait for asynchronous I/O completion if any
                ::GetOverlappedResult(file, &overlapped, &dummy, TRUE);

                HANDLE hEvent = _InterlockedExchange(&overlapped_array[i].hEvent, 0);

                if (hEvent) ::CloseHandle(hEvent);
            }

            // it is safe to close the file here because the file will be closed internally by the kernel
            // only after all I/O asynchronous operations on this file complete
            ::CloseHandle(file);
            file = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }

        delete[] filename;
        filename = nullptr;
    }
```

EDIT: Events need to be explicitly closed but as suggested by Hans, it is better to close them AFTER closing the file.

```
    void Close()
    {
        HANDLE hFile = _InterlockedExchange(&file, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
        {
            // it is safe to close the file here because the file will be closed internally by the kernel
            // only after all I/O asynchronous operations on this file complete
            ::CloseHandle(hFile);

            for (long i = 0; i < overlapped_max; ++i)
            {
                ::CloseHandle(overlapped_array[i].hEvent);
            }
        }

        delete[] filename;
        filename = nullptr;
    }
```

Now, I still have a question regarding with "it is safe to close the file here because the file will be closed internally by the kernel only after all I/O asynchronous operations on this file complete". i don't remember whether I wrote this or quoted a Microsoft statement. Supposedly that the file is opened twice, would this call to CloseHandle with a specific file handle wait for all I/O completion done through this specific handle? if not, closing event handle just AFTER closing the file handle is not safe at all.

Comment: You have to clean up.  Little point in waiting for the I/O request to complete, just close the file and *then* close the event handle.  Do watch out for code in another thread that is waiting for the event, it is going to get an unpleasant surprise of course.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks. So it means those event handles will leak if they are not closed explicitly.

Comment: Is closing event handles after closing a file handle always safe when several file handles were opened on the same file?

Comment: Not if the overlapped I/O was started on one of those other handle.

Comment: @HansPassant You have to wait for the I/O to complete because the kernel may be writing results to the output buffers, and it will certainly write to the OVERLAPPED structure when the I/O completes. Abandoning I/O without waiting for it to complete leads to mysterious memory corruption bugs.

Comment: Hmm, surely not after the file was closed.

Comment: Let me elaborate my question:

I created a class to handle an asynchronous file mostly for logging purpose, using a ring of N buffers and with an event handle for each buffer. The purpose is to issue several lines of logging without blocking the thread as much as possible. If I create two instances of this class on the same file and I close the first instance while there is still an I/O pending. Will FileClose on the first handle be blocked until all I/O complete even if the refcount is not 0 (because there is another handle on the same file)?

Comment: "all I/O complete": only I/O operations done through the first handle of course

Comment: @Hans: I don't think you're allowed to close a handle with pending I/O.

Comment: "[CloseHandle is synchronous. Note that its return may not mean every OVERLAPPED will be updated, because that's done by user mode APCs which are asynchronous.](https://www.osronline.com/ShowThread.cfm?link=213975)"

Comment: No APC is involved, the file system driver writes directly into the buffer.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I'm not using any callback mechanism involving APC because I call WriteFile and not WriteFileEx. Or do you really mean the inner implementation of WriteFile uses an user APC to handle OVERLAPPED?

Comment: I don't know. I was just quoting someone else. Just play it safe. Wait for the I/O to complete before continuing. If, as you expect, the I/O has already completed, then the wait will return immediately and nobody gets hurt.